# Read from pipe multiple times

Tags: linux, bash, openssl, pipe

I have a bash script which uses openssl to connect to server. All output of openssl are redirected to pipe and server input data is being passed through another pipe. But when i'm trying to read from server output pipe more than one time it freezes.

```
openssl s_client \
    -starttls xmpp \
    -xmpphost "$domain" \
    -connect "$host:$port" \
    -quiet \
    < $topipe \
    > $frompipe &

echo "somedata" > $topipe

# Works fine
read -t 1 serverresponse < "$frompipe"

#
# Do some stuff....
#

# Freezes
read -t 1 serverresponse < "$frompipe"
```

How to fix this?

Comment: should work when putting the two read's into one block (of curly brackets) and redirecting ONCE into that block instead of twice into each read command (untested)

Comment: To troubleshoot, can you run `topipe=/dev/null` followed by your `openssl ...` command ? To see if the second `read` works.

Comment: [This is my IMAP client in Bash](https://pastebin.com/BFLdS4gA) that writes / reads multiple requests / responses to / from a pipe. The main caveat is that just redirecting a command’s output into a pipe closes the pipe once the command finishes, which will also cause the pipe’s consumer to reach the end of its input. That said, if you want multiple commands to write into a pipe, you need to concatenate their outputs, either using something like `{ echo a; echo b; } > pipe`, or the same kind of construct with a subshell, or something similar as a function (`{}`-style or subshell-style).